# Dynamically sort in Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

In Django admin, 
Is it possible that dynamically sort by field name using url param?

In this way,
https://www.example.com/admin/blog/article/?order=modified_date
https://www.example.com/admin/blog/article/?order=deleted_date

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your version of Django, you can use the [get_ordering()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_ordering) method in your ModelAdmin class.

Comment: Thanks! but, i redirected ?e=1. (Django 1.4.5) using GET parameters in get_ordering.

Comment: Please edit your question and show the code that you are using.